# Stirah: is snow good or bad in Judaism?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

On the one hand, we pray that our sins should become white like snow (kashelek yalbinu). On the other hand, we repeatedly find snow representing negative feelings: "Vayosifu Od SNOW oso" and "Eis le'ehov v'eis li'SNOW". So which is it?

P.S: Additional mekoros about snow welcome.

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: In Taanit, gemorah says that snow is 5 times better then rain. And we all know that rain is good (at least at winter)

Comment: I think you could have made this into a real question with a little effort

Comment: What about "לא תירא כל ביתה משלג", which is "שלג של גהנם"?

Comment: [****groan****]

Comment: There is'now easy answer for this one.

Answer (score 1):

A great question.

I think the basis for an answer lies in the *mishnayot* of *negaim* (נגעים).

The brightest shade of white for a *nega* is "Snow White"(to elaborate on this would be off topic...). Although one may argue that *tzaraas* is a symbol of impurity, but we must remeber the *klal* of "כולו הפך לבן - טהור". The snow symbolizes the *tikkun* needed, but at last white is the pure, whole color we all aspire to.